Laravel Eloquent - Using Mariadb variables with HAVING
I am having an issue filtering a Mariadb query through HAVING on a computed column based on a Mariadb variable.
I am having an issue in Laravel Elquent where a query I am running is producing no results.
I have found the offending part of the query and have dumbed down the query as much as I can as a test.
Executing this code, in Laravel, yields the result "0":
    dd(\DB::table('timesheets')->select([
        'timesheets.*',
        DB::raw('(@test := 1) AS test1'),
        DB::raw('@test AS test2'),
    ])->havingRaw('test2 = 1')->count());

But if I output the SQL:
    dd(\DB::table('timesheets')->select([
        'timesheets.*',
        DB::raw('(@test := 1) AS test1'),
        DB::raw('@test AS test2'),
    ])->havingRaw('test2 = 1')->toSql());

select timesheets.*, (@test := 1) AS test1, @test AS test2 from timesheets having test2 = 1
And run this query directly against my Mariadb instance using tableplus, I get the results I expect.
If I alter the query to be:
    dd(\DB::table('timesheets')->select([
        'timesheets.*',
        DB::raw('1 AS test1'),
        DB::raw('1 AS test2'),
    ])->havingRaw('test2 = 1')->count());

Then I get the result "66503" which is correct.
It seems that there is some overhead (somewhere!) within Laravel that doesn't like the variables within the select statements, used in conjunction with MySql's HAVING, but my query relies heavily on this.
I'd be grateful for any help as I am tearing my hair out with this one!

I've tested select users.*, (@test := 1) AS test1, @test AS test2 from users having  test2 = 1; and I don't get any result.  To retirve something the query must be:  select * from (select the-table.*, (@test := 1) AS test1, @test AS test2 from the-table) ttt where test2 = 1

@TUPKAP See this is interesting, because when I run this exact same query as you (I have a users table also), I get a result (every row in the table)...

To be precise I use MariaDb 10.11.6

I remember running into this problem years ago. My solution was to declare the sql variable in a statement before the query with DB::statement() and then using it in a query right after.

Also sad to inform you that Eloquent is no longer maintained. The query also looks odd and there is probably ways to achieve it without user variables at all. Can you clarify the results you are after and maybe something better can be implemented?

@danblack I don't think it's laravel-related

@IGP I'm essentially trying to avoid running the same logic per-row that I intend to use multiple times.

Looking at the MySQL docs, I think what I am trying to do isn't the right approach "There is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment... To avoid problems with this behavior, do not assign a value to and read the value of the same variable within a single statement... "

right - edit question to show the results you expect.

Use this approach:


dd( \DB::table('timesheets')
    ->select([
        'timesheets.*',
    ])
    ->havingRaw('(SELECT @test := 1) AND (@test = 1)')
    ->count());




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I don't know how you do this in laravel, but typically you initialize variables in a cross join:
select timesheets.*, @test AS test2
from (select @test:=1) init
cross join timesheets
having test2 = 1

Though in 10.4 and above, there is very little need for setting user variables in a select.
